# Publish the APK in Google play store with "V4" signature

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, apk, mobile-security

I am new to mobile development and using React Native in my project.
I am trying to publish/release my APK in the play store signed with a V4 signature.
Unlike other V1, V2 and V3 signatures which are included in the APK file itself V4 has a separate **idsig** file. So How can we upload two files on the play store or can we include the V4 signature in APK as well?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it is designed to upload an v4 signature. Most likely such signatures are created in the Google cloud when you upload the private key into the Google Cloud.

Comment: Is it possible to verify if the uploaded APK on the play store is V4 signed as it will not be having the idsig file with it?